# Matrix View in Function Doesn't Have Side Effects

Tags: python, numpy

**Edit**:  I've found what the problem boils down to:

If you run this code:

```
A = ones((10,4))
view = A[:,1]
view.fill(7)
A
```

or

```
A = ones((10,4))
view = A[:,1:3]
view.fill(7)
A
```

You'll see that the columns of A change

If you run this:

```
A = ones((10,4))
view = A[:,(1,2)]
view.fill(7)
A
```

There's no side effects on A.  Is this behavior on purpose or a bug?

I have a function that calculates the amount I have to rotate certain columns of x,y points in a matrix.  The function only takes one input - a matrix mat:

```
def rotate(mat):
```

In the function, I create views to make working with each section easier:

```
rot_mat = mat[:,(col,col+1)]
```

Then, I calculate a rotation angle and apply it back on the view that I had created before:

```
rot_mat[row,0] = cos(rot)*x - sin(rot)*y
rot_mat[row,1] = sin(rot)*x + cos(rot)*y
```

If I perform this in the main body of my program, the changes to my rot_mat view would propagate to the original matrix mat.  When I turned it into a function, the views stopped having side effects on the original matrix.  What's the reasoning for this and is there any way to get around it?  I should also note that it isn't changing mat within the function itself.  At the end, I just try to return mat but no changes have been made.

Full code for function:

```
def rotate(mat):
    # Get a reference shape
    ref_sh = 2*random.choice(range(len(filelist)))
    print 'Reference shape is '
    print (ref_sh/2)
    # Create a copy of the reference point matrix
    ref_mat = mat.take([ref_sh,ref_sh+1],axis=1)
    # Calculate rotation for each set of points
    for col in range(len(filelist)):
        col = col * 2 # Account for the two point columns
        rot_mat = mat[:,(col,col+1)]
        # Numerator = sum of wi*yi - zi*xi
        numer = inner(ref_mat[:,0],rot_mat[:,1]) - inner(ref_mat[:,1],rot_mat[:,0])
        # Denominator = sum of wi*xi + zi*yi
        denom = inner(ref_mat[:,0],rot_mat[:,0]) + inner(ref_mat[:,1],rot_mat[:,1])
        rot = arctan(numer/denom)
        # Rotate the points in rot_mat.  As it's a view of mat, the effects are
        # propagated.
        for row in range(num_points):
            x = rot_mat[row,0]
            y = rot_mat[row,1]
            rot_mat[row,0] = cos(rot)*x - sin(rot)*y
            rot_mat[row,1] = sin(rot)*x + cos(rot)*y
    return mat
```

Comment: Whether or not the code is in a function should make no difference. Could you include a runnable example that demonstrates this behaviour?

Comment: @aix I added the full code for my function.  I'm working on producing a runnable example now.

Comment: Thank you. I think that'll make it much easier for us to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @aix I added quick runnable examples of the problem I'm experiencing.  Passing a tuple seems to be throwing the view off.

Comment: The funny thing is that `A[:,(1,2)] = 0` does modify `A`, but introducing the variable `view` changes the behavior. I can explain how that happens (`__getitem__` vs. `__setitem__`), but it's still very surprising and looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `view = A[:,(1,2)]` you are using advanced indexing ([Numpy manual: Advanced Indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing)), which means that the array returns a copy, not a view. It's advanced because your indexing object is a tuple "containing at least one sequence" (the sequence being the tuple `(1,2)`). The total explicit selection object `obj` in your case would equal `(slice(None), (1,2))`, i.e. `A[(slice(None), (1,2))]` returns the same thing as `A[:,(1,2)]`.

As larsmans suggests above, it seems that `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` behave differently for advanced indexing, which makes sense, because assigning values to a copy would have no use (the copy would not be stored).